# How to run Selenium WebDriver test cases in Chrome for mobile site

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

how to run my selenium 'webdriver' with google chrome for mobile site, not getting any clue to run my scripts,

i have user agent for the firefox like and running my test cases easily in firefox for mobile site

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.addExtension(new File(CONFIG.getProperty("agentswitcher")));
String samsung3 = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-de; Galaxy S II Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30";
ffProfile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", samsung3);
```

here agent switcher is the `user_agent_switcher-0.7.3-fx+sm.xpi` file download it from web

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

You need to pass a param of `ChromeOptions` to constructor of `ChromeDriver`

**The code is the next:**

```
string device = "Samsung Galaxy S4";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.EnableMobileEmulation(device);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);//this will open Chrome in mobile mode
```

List of available devices you can get from Chrome mobile emulator.

**Some of them are:** "Apple iPhone 4", "Apple iPhone 6", "Samsung Galaxy S4"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to launch chrome browser in mobile view

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");

Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>(); mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation); ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options) driver.get("http://google.com");
log.info(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();